# CSS flex and space-between dynamic

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Right now my code shows 4 column divs. Each div is 47% in width. If you only have 2 column divs, it works perfectly.

But if you have 4 column divs, how can you make it so that there is 2 divs per row without closing the "flex" div and then opening another "flex" div?

What if I have 12 column divs, how can I do it dynamically where there is only 2 divs per row?

```css
.flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.column {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;

    width: 47%;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
    <div class="column">Hi</div>
    <div class="column">Hi</div>

    <div class="column">Hi</div> <!-- This should be a new row... -->
    <div class="column">Hi</div>
</div>
```

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/htf931bq/

Comment: i just mentioned in the comment. Do not share code in jsfiddle but add it in the code snippet....

Comment: @MihaiT OP has had their code in the question since the first version of the post, which is all that the rules require. If you would like a runnable snippet, you should edit the question to convert the code to a runnable snippet in the future, rather than waiting for OP to try and discover and use a new site feature.

Comment: @TylerH the SO snippet is not new and it's there for exactly this purpose. [stackOverflow code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) In this case, so people can test right away the code and then they can `copy snippet to answer` and just edit it. Much less time consuming than with an external link or just a pasted code. Which benefits both the ones that want to help and the OP. Plus, maybe the OP will post another question or an answer in the future and knowing how to use the code snippet might be usefull.

Comment: @MihaiT The stack snippet feature is new (like all things are new) to a user who is new. OP is a low rep user who is relatively new to the site and has posted relatively few times, so it's entirely possible for them to be unaware of what you're talking about. At any rate, my previous point stands; you have editing capabilities and OP provided an MCVE... why can't you spend a moment converting it to a snippet rather than writing a comment?

Answer (score 3):

You have to set a dimension for the wrapper, than give all columns a flex basis of 47% and add a wrap attribute to the container:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f9du6po/)

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.column {
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    flex: 0 0 47%;  
}

<div class="flex">
<div class="column">Hi</div>
<div class="column">Hi</div>

<div class="column">Hi</div> <!-- This should be a new row... -->
<div class="column">Hi</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
.flex {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

So now you'll have 2 columns, each 47% width.
But you'll have to add a media query in order to make it user friendly for mobile devices.

Add this media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
         width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: and it is not even good behavior to ask to accept the answer without verifying that it is indeed the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...

I just added `flex-wrap: wrap;` to the flex class like this:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

Comment: Yes but do not use width to the column, just give 'em a flex-basis value